# How to Data to an existing delta table in databricks?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I am having data in parquet format in ADLS gen2. I want to implement dalta layers in my project.
So I kept all the data from on-prem in ADLS Gen2 via ADF in a separate container called landing zone.

Now i created a separated container called Bronze where I want to keep delta table.
For this I have did like below.
I have created a database in databricks. And I have created a delta table in data bricks using below SQL code.

```
create table if not exists externaltables.actv_snap_view(
id String,
mbr_id String,
typ_id String,
strt_dttm String,
otcome_typ_id String,
cdc String
)
using delta
location '/mnt/Storage/Bronze/actv_snap_view'
```

Now my table is not having any data.

1. How can I add data which is in data lake landing zone into delta table which I created.
2. My database is in databricks after data is added to the table where will be the underlined data will be stored.

Comment: If externaltables.actv_snap_view is your Destination table then  you can  insert data from your parquet

insert into externaltables.actv_snap_view select * from parquet.`your adls location`  your adls location should be enclosed within backticks

Comment: While creating the Database if you can specify Location pointing to your adls then DB will be created there.

Similarly if for tables if you specify the location then the data will be copied there.

Comment: If Location is not specified then its copied to default /dbfs location

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the steps below to create table using data from `landingzone` (source for parquet files), where the table belongs to the database present in `bronze` container.

- Considering your ADLS containers are mounted, you can create a database and specify its location as your `bronze` container mount point as suggested by `@Ganesh Chandrasekaran`.

```
create database demo location "/mnt/bronzeoutput/"
```

- Now use the following SQL syntax to create a table using parquet file present in mount point of the `landingzone` container.

```
create table demo.<table_name> (<columns>) using parquet location '/mnt/landingzoneinput/<parquet_file_name>';
```

Using the above steps, you have created a database in your `bronze` container where you can store your tables. To populate a table created inside this database of `bronze` container, you are using the files present in your `landingzone` container.

**Update:**

- Using the `create table` statement above is creating a table with data from the parquet file, but this table does not reflect in the data lake.
- You can instead use the query given below. It first creates a table in the database (present in `bronze` container). Now you can insert the values from your parquet file present in `landingzone`.

```
create table demo.<table_name> (<columns>);
-- demo database is inside bronze container

insert into demo.<table_name> select * from <data_source>.`/mnt/landingzoneinput/source_file`
```